# flutter list of clickable images

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a good listview working with a leading image, title and its clickable.  I wanted to try and get it to be just a list of images with text on top of it.  I have looked at gridview, but really just need 1 image per line. This is my listview code.  Can this be changed or do I need to rewrite it to make this work.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new RefreshIndicator(
        child: new ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: _itemBuilder,
            itemCount: mylist.length,
        ),
        onRefresh: _onRefresh,

    ));
  }

  Widget _itemBuilder (BuildContext context, int index) {
    Specialties spec = getSpec(index);
    return new SpecialtyWidget(spec: spec,);

  }

  Specialties getSpec(int index) {
    return new Specialties(mylist[index]['id'], mylist[index]['name'], mylist[index]['details'], new Photo('lib/images/'+mylist[index]['image'], mylist[index]['name'], mylist[index]['name']));
    //return new Specialties.fromMap(mylist[index]);

  }

class SpecialtyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  SpecialtyWidget({Key key, this.spec}) : super(key: key);

  final Specialties spec;

  @override
  _SpecialtyWidgetState createState() => new _SpecialtyWidgetState();
}

class _SpecialtyWidgetState extends State<SpecialtyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new ListTile(
      leading: new Image.asset(widget.spec.pic.assetName),
      //title: new Text(widget.spec.name),
      onTap: _onTap,
    );
  }

  void _onTap() {
    Route route = new MaterialPageRoute(
      settings: new RouteSettings(name: "/specs/spec"),
      builder: (BuildContext context) => new SpecPage(spec: widget.spec),
    );
    Navigator.of(context).push(route);
  }
}
```

If it will not work with the listview any guidance would be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having a hard time understanding your question, but it sounds like you want the entries in your list to use a different layout than the one provided by [`ListTile`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html).

You could use a [`Stack`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) to put text on top of your images (compositing them together) or a [`Column`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html) if you want to put text vertically above your images. You can also use other [Flutter layout widgets](https://flutter.io/tutorials/layout/) to ensure that the text appears in the right place.

Comment: I will try that for the text on image, the bigger thing is how to get just images in a list view, just 1 per line, gridview seems to be geared to multiple per line. I am going to try to remove ListTile and just return an image and see if that works.

Comment: So changing my return to an image worked and a stack does get text on the picture, but can not get it centered and on the bottom of the picture.  Sure I will find it soon.  Thanks for your help again.

Comment: Your `Stack` has an alignment property, you can try  `FractionalOffset.bottomCenter`. Or use a `Column` or `Row`. Read the Flutter layout tutorial I linked for more ideas.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, last point is clickable images, I do not see a property on there for onTap or pressed, etc...  Any thoughts on how to now make the image clickable like the ListTile was?

Comment: Try using an InkWell or GestureRecognizer